# Urine for Mouthwash

Tags: oral-health, urine, gums, mouthwash, gingivitis

I have heard of people using urine as a mouthwash. There are a lot of claims that it helps to cure a variety of dental problems, such as gum inflammation. So far, I can only find anecdotal evidence.

What properties of urine would make it a beneficial mouthwash?

Comment: Yuck!!! Sorry I don't have a more helpful comment here!

Comment: If it triggers your gag reflex, it's very counter-productive.